# Terraform variable pointing to current file name

Tags: terraform

**Is there some special variable available in Terraform configuration files which would point to current file name?**

I'd like to use it for description fields in various resources, so that someone seeing these resources in the systems would know where is the master definition for them.

e.g.

in `myinfra.tf`

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "my_policy" {
  name        = "something-important"
  description = "Managed by Terraform at ${HERE_I_WOULD_LIKE_TO_USE_THE_VARIABLE}"

  policy = <<EOF
[...]
EOF
}
```

And I would hope the description becomes:

```
description = "Managed by Terraform at myinfra.tf"
```

---

I tried `${path.module}` but that only gives "filesystem path of the module where the expression is placed", so pragmatically speaking - everything but the file name I want.

Comment: I don't think you can do it. But then how would it work if later you would rename your files, or re-organize your infrastracture into modules? Re-deploy or change all the resources?

Comment: After renaming files / moving resources between files, the values would evaluate to something else and next `terraform apply` would see them as changed. Just like any other variable.

Comment: I'd recommend not putting that in the description but rather use tags. That way you can find those Terraform managed resources easier and you can use the description for something meaningful. And AFAIK there is no way to get the current file name. Not sure if that is really necessary though. We have tags to show a resource is managed by Terraform and a tag with the link to the projects Git repository where the Terraform is managed. So far, that was sufficient.

Comment: @Jens I guess you mean AWS specifically, but not all vendors / systems support tags.

Comment: @GrzegorzOledzki Yeah. Not sure about other public clouds. My suggestion is for AWS.

Comment: @Jens also even if narrowing to AWS specifically, my nice-to-have would be for the tag value to have name of the file, not only the Git repo we are in.

Comment: I think you would need to pre-process the TF files before plan/apply, or just have some tiny wrapper around apply/plan commands which would perform simple find-and-replace on your tf scripts to inject tf file names where needed.

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I can share. Use the [data external resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) to call an external script that would get the directory/file name and then return it back as a string or any other type that your resources require. Obviously it's not exactly what you wanted as you'll get the dir/file name indirectly but hopefully it helps for others or even yourself for use-cases.

We use that only for azurerm and for very complex integrations that are not yet supported with the current provider versions. I have have not tested it specifically for AWS but since it's a core Terraform resource provider, I'm guessing it might work across the board.

```
data "external" "cwd" {
  program = ["./script.sh"]
  query = {
    cwd = "${path.cwd}"
  }
}
```

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "my_policy" {
  name        = "something-important"
  description = "Managed by Terraform at ${data.external.dir_script.result.filename}"

  policy = <<EOF
[...]
EOF
```

This is how my script looks like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

#echo '{"cwd":"for_testing"}' | ./dir_name.sh  | xargs

PIPED=`cat`
errPrint "INFO: Got PIPED data:\n$PIPED"

DIR=`jq -r .cwd <<< $PIPED`

cd $DIR
filename=`ls | grep \.tf$ | xargs`
errPrint "INFO: Returning this as STDOUT:${filename}"

echo "{\"name\":\"$filename\"}"
```

You need to be that the data from the script needs to return a valid JSON object.

> The program must then produce a valid JSON object on stdout, which will be used to populate the result attribute exported to the rest of the Terraform configuration. This JSON object must again have all of its values as strings. On successful completion it must exit with status zero.

Unfortunately, like the others mentioned, there's no other way to get the current file name being 'applied'.

Comment: How would `dir_name.sh` get the name of the TF file from which it is called?

Comment: You're right I might have gotten ahead of myself - with what I had in mind, it would still require having a value in the file that the script can pick, like finding a string in a file.

Comment: Hi @Marcin can you verify if this could work for him? I tweaked my script to fit the scenario and also using `${path.cwd}`. I added `xargs` in the event there are more than one file... Would appreciate feedback

Comment: Nice hack. In order to fit my use-case, I guess the `script.sh` would need to do more precise grepping - as the whole point of putting the name of the `.tf` file is to point to a specific one among plenty of them.

Comment: Yes and I guess with a proper naming convention for different files, it should be possible to get it right.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might benefit from using something like [yor](https://github.com/bridgecrewio/yor) from [Bridge Crew](https://bridgecrew.io/).

From the project's README:

> Yor is an open-source tool that helps add informative and consistent tags across infrastructure-as-code frameworks such as Terraform, CloudFormation, and Serverless.
>
> Yor is built to run as a GitHub Action automatically adding consistent tagging logics to your IaC. Yor can also run as a pre-commit hook and a standalone CLI.

So basically, it updates your resources tags with things like:

```
   tags   = {
      env                  = var.env
      yor_trace            = "912066a1-31a3-4a08-911b-0b06d9eac64e"
      git_repo             = "example"
      git_org              = "bridgecrewio"
      git_file             = "applyTag.md"
      git_commit           = "COMMITHASH"
      git_modifiers        = "bana/gandalf"
      git_last_modified_at = "2021-01-08 00:00:00"
      git_last_modified_by = "bana@bridgecrew.io"
   }
```

Maybe that would be good enough to provide what you're trying to do?

As far as my testimony, I have not used `yor` since my tagging uses a different approach.  Instead of having "raw" tags, we use a label module that builds the tags for us and then merges in local tags.

Just sharing this info FYI in case it helps.